# Would this redirect script open me up for code injection or remote file inclusion?

Tags: php, redirect, code-injection, remote-file-inclusion

Recently I ran across a blog article about using PHP scripts to redirect affiliate links.  It got me thinking whether this script was safe or not.  I've heard that using the $_GET variable can lead to a vulnerability.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Would checking the input for alphanumerics and the hyphen ('-') be enough to guard against this?

For this script, links in would be of the form:

`http://www.somesite.com/amazon.php?asin=XXXXXXXXXX`

or

`http://www.somesite.com/amazon.php?id=some-keyword`

Here is amazon.php:

```
   <?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $asin = $_GET['asin'];

    if ($asin != NULL)
    {
        header("Location:http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/".$asin."/fantasticaffiliate-20");
        exit;
    }

    else
    {
        $links = array(
            "keyword-one" => "http://www.amazon.com/b/?node=1122334455&tag=fantasticaffiliate-20",
            "keyword-two" => "http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/1352434213/fantasticaffiliate-20"
            );          

        header("Location:".$links[$id]);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Thanks as always!

Comment: Side note:  How did the rads.stackoverflow.com link get substituted into my question?  That wasn't the text I posted.  (The links were fictitious as well, of course.  I didn't post live affiliate links.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would. None of those characters in any combination is enough to cause a XSS problem.